# Android, reusable toolbar for navigation - where to put code?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-menu

I want to implement a toolbar for navigation which appears at the bottom of almost all activities in my app. It will have a fixed amout of elements (four).

Screenshot: 
(certain activities will still have their own toolbar at the top):

[image: already done]

In order to make it somewhat reusable, I've created a separate layout file for the toolbar which allows me to include it on multiple activities with:

```
<include android:id="@+id/toolbar_main" layout="@layout/toolbar_main" />
```

Every item of the toolbar leads to another activity, which means it acts as a navigation throughout the whole application.

However, as I want to use it on multiple activities, I'm not sure on what would be the correct place for the Java-Code behind the onClick-Events of the menu items. I've seen approaches using a base-class which can be extended by all activities using this navigation toolbar. I've also thought about not using a toolbar at all and creating a fragment for the navigation. I haven't used fragments yet, however, they seem to have their own code-behind class in addition to their design .xml, which would be suitable for the click-Events. Any suggestions? I might add, that I want to center and stretch the navigation bar later on, which seems to be not so easy using a Toolbar with associated menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make A Base activity, which will be extending by all your other activities. Write all your logic related to that toolbar on Base Activity. Thats all.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `TabLayout` with `ViewPager`. Place them in main `Activity`, and use `Fragment` for every root screen.

Comment: How would I deal with additional activities/fragments, which can be reached from within the four major views? For example, there will be a detail activity for feeds, which won't be part of the navigation, but has to display it nevertheless.

Comment: It is not recommended doing this because it is not a normal case on android apps. Its better to open another Activity without the TabLayout, this way you will manage better the app flow. But if you have to do anyway, you can continue adding fragments to main Activity and remove them, for instance, when you click another tab or after some action. But it is not a good practise and the code will be a real mess at the end.