# Android Toolbar with activities and fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-toolbar

So I have a grocery project to work on, and it is required that I have to have a toolbar all. Just a toolbar that includes the `name` of the current Activity/Fragment, and a `back button`.

I searched on Stackoverflow, and all the answers were either 'use ViewPager' or 'use Tabs'. There was an answer here that was very close, but it was `toolbar in multiple activities`.
([Android, reusable toolbar for navigation - where to put code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942653/android-reusable-toolbar-for-navigation-where-to-put-code))

So, I have to have the main Activity that contains a static fragment, and different category buttons (for the products) that lead to different fragments that contain the product.

**My question is**: If I put the Toolbar code in the Main Activity, will it automatically appear in the fragments I call from it, and the fragments from those fragments?

Thank you!

Comment: It depends on your Activity's layout. Toolbars and Fragments are both types of views that can be in a layout. For your case, it sounds like you could create a layout for your activity that has a Toolbar in it, as well as a FrameLayout that you can place fragments in. When you make fragment transactions, you would pass the FrameLayout to the `replace` function as the "container".

Comment: @Tenfour04 thank you so much! So if I understand it right: if I `replace` as the `container` in the fragment transaction, it doesn't matter if it's from the activity to the base fragment, or from the base fragment to later fragments, I will be able to keep it? Sorry for the redundancy, I'm new to all this!

Comment: I would suggest to use Navigation.
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation

That way you can have an Activity which hosts the fragments and you can manage the toolbar easily within the navigation. That will solve the need of using either back button or close button. And it's the most updated Android standard

Comment: @FernandoPrieto Thank you! I did a lot of trial and errors, and it worked! I just checked my build.gradle app, and it's in there so I think I'm safe!